# Using local variables in ExternalEvaluate Python

Tags: interoperability, python

I am sure that I am missing something here, I have some larger matrices and Mathematica takes too long to compute the eigenvalues and vectors (using `Eigensystem[m]`) so I would like to pass them to a python environment using `ExternalEvaluate` so as to take advantage of Python's much faster computation for this.

I am sure there is an easy way to pass my matrix to Python, but I cannot see how.

MWE:

```
In[1]:= linearMap = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
             {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0},
             {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/4}};

In[2]:= ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import numpy; numpy.linalg.eigvalsh(linearMap)"]
Out[2]=
```

[image]

I am very aware that it is not necessary for such small matrices (or indeed this matrix at all really!), but as they get larger, I would greatly appreciate the ability to utilise the speed increases.

Clearly this isn't expected to work instantly as the `linearMap` from Mathematica would need to be reformatted to a Python array. I am just hoping that there is an easy way to do this that I have overlooked...

Comment: MMA evalutes the eigensystem in  0.005s , that's to long???

Comment: As I said, the issue is not with this matrix, but for much larger matrices that I need to use. This is simply a Minimum Working Example.

Comment: I'm wondering if your speed issue arises because you feed exact numbers to `Eigensystem`, as in your `linearMap` example.  If so, use `Eigensystem[N@linearMap]` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use the [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) syntax for [`ExternalEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html).

If `numpy` is installed in your Python instance then you should have a `"Python-NumPy"` external evaluator.  Check by evaluating `FindExternalEvaluators[]`.

Initialise the connection with

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python-NumPy", "1+1"]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Then

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python-NumPy",
 <|
  "Command" -> "numpy.linalg.eigvalsh",
  "Arguments" -> {linearMap}
 |>
]
```

> ```
> {0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1., 1., 1.}
> ```

If you need to use this often then create a function

```
numpyEigvalsh[m_?MatrixQ] :=
 ExternalEvaluate["Python-NumPy",
  <|
   "Command" -> "numpy.linalg.eigvalsh",
   "Arguments" -> {m}
  |>
 ]
```

Then

```
numpyEigvalsh@linearMap
```

> ```
> {0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1., 1., 1.}
> ```

## Why it may be slower

Note that when using [`Rationals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationals.html) that Mathematica will take longer as it works to preserve the infinite precision of rationals.

```
Eigenvalues@linearMap
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1/4, 1/4}

You can speed things up by using [`Reals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals.html). All you need to do is multiply by `1.`

```
Eigenvalues[1. linearMap]
```

> ```
> {1., 1., 1., 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25}
> ```

Note that the output is now with reals instead of rationals

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to setup and use [WolframClientForPython](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython) you could do:

With *Mathematica*

```
linearMap = 1. {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 0, 0, 0}, 
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0}, 
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/4}};
Export[FileNameJoin[{"C:", "temp", "linearMap.wxf"}], "WXF"]
```

then in Python

```
import numpy as np
import os
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.serializers import export

math_kernel = r'C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.3\MathKernel.exe'
output_path = r'C:\temp'

session = WolframLanguageSession(math_kernel)
session.start()

linear_map = session.evaluate('Import[FileNameJoin[{"C:", "temp", "linearMap.wxf"}]]')

linear_map = np.array(linear_map)

out = np.linalg.eigvalsh(linear_map)

export(out, os.path.join(output_path, 'out.wxf'), target_format='wxf')

session.terminate()
```

finally back in *Mathematica*

```
Import[FileNameJoin[{"C:", "temp", "out.wxf"}]] // Normal
(* {0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1., 1., 1.} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the *association* as suggested by Edmund
(or if you want to do something more general with the matrix than just sending it as an argument of a function), use `ExportString` with the option `"PythonExpression"`:

```
Py[ex_] := ExportString[ex, "PythonExpression"] 
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import numpy; numpy.linalg.eigvalsh(" <> Py[linearMap] <> ")"]
```

Notice that you will obtain the result will in the form of `NumericArray`, which can be transformed to a regular list by `Normal[%]`.

Comment: Per ExternalEvaluate[] docs: Add two numbers in Python using an inline TemplateExpression:
`x = 42;`
`ExternalEvaluate[session, "1 + <* x *>"]`

Out[2]= 43