# ExternalEvaluate not running the whole Python file

Tags: python, external-calls

I have the following 'test.py' written in Python:

```
import numpy as np

f = open('normals.txt', 'r')

content = f.read()
print(content)
```

and I want to execute it from Mathematica using:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[session, File["~/test.py"]]
```

but when I run this, I get the error:

[image]

Following the answer given in [Using local variables in ExternalEvaluate Python](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185338/using-local-variables-in-externalevaluate-python), I have checked that `numpy` is already installed, by running `FindExternalEvaluators[]` where I get a table with `Python`, `Python-NumPy`, `Python-PIL`, etc. so I guess everything is fine. Now, I should run:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python-NumPy"]
```

However, it returns a failure with the session specification, `StartExternalSession::invalidSpec`. How can I `ExternalEvaluate` a Python code which has `import numpy` in it?

Comment: My first thought is that you have multiple instances of Python installed on your computer, and Mathematica just seems to run the wrong one. Try ``ExternalEvaluate[session, "import sys; print(sys.executable)"]`` and see whether the path is correct. Did you install ``numpy`` via pip? Do you use conda environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try registering the external evaluator (Python or other). You just have to locate the path where you have it installed.

[image]

Test:

[image]